# Hive data loading

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have dataset which is tab separated and line terminated by new line. Each line contains 5 tab separated data.
eg dataset,

```
XXXX1 XXXX2 XXXX3 XXXX4 XXXX5
```

Now i have to create a table with 3 columns first two columns will store values `XXXX1` and `XXXX2` respectively for the first line and third column should contain remaining values `XXXX3 XXXX4 XXXX5`.

I created the table using the below query, but holding only  `XXXX3` in the third column remaining two data are not loading into the table.

```
create table x( 
id string, name string,country string, emails string
) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t';
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I would recommend you to create a table with 5 columns and create view on top of this table. You can do `concat` or `concat_ws` in your view to get the desired output. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Comment: Hi @Ambrish Thanks for your quick reply. The last three values are email ids, so person can have more than 3 emails. That's why i wanted to store the remaining values in the 3rd column as comma separated. Is there any way i can define this while creating the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tblproperties ('serialization.last.column.takes.rest'='true')**

```
create table x
(
     id string, name string,country string, emails string
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t'
stored as textfile
tblproperties ('serialization.last.column.takes.rest'='true')
;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dudu Markovitz it's a great help.